# Android MotionEvent gets changed/corrupted by Jetpack Compose MutableState

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have an Jetpack Compose drawing app that is passing finger touch MotionEvents from a top-level motion event handler down to a Jetpack Compose `Canvas`.

The handler intercepts motion events using a `pointerInteropFilter` modifier on a `Box`, and passes them to a `MutableState<MotionEvent?>` which is shared with the `Canvas`.

Everything works fine, except when the `Canvas` receives the `MotionEvent` through the `MutableState`, the `y` coordinate has been changed to be the same as the `RawY` coordinate, meaning what's drawn in the Canvas is offset by the thickness of the app's topbar plus the phone's notification bar.

Either `MutableState` has some bug that mangles `MotionEvents`, or (far more likely) I am doing it wrong!

Here are logs I took of the `MotionEvent` as it was sent from the handler, and as it was received by the `Canvas`.

```
TouchMngrScreen: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=254.9707, y[0]=158.92944, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=1685820, downTime=1685820, deviceId=6, source=0x5002, displayId=0 }
InkCanvasScreen: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=254.9707, y[0]=483.92944, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=1685820, downTime=1685820, deviceId=6, source=0x5002, displayId=0 }
```

Everything is the same, except the `Y` is now the same as `RawY`. (You can't see RawY in the log, but I logged it out separately, and it's the value that is appearing as `Y`.)

My `MutableState` is defined like this:

```
val mutableMotionEvent: MutableState<MotionEvent?> = remember { mutableStateOf(value=null, policy = neverEqualPolicy()) }
```

The handler sets it like this:

```
mutableMotionEvent.value = event
```

And the `Canvas` reads it like this:

```
Canvas(
   modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxSize()
    .border(border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Green))

) {
    mutableMotionEvent.value?.let {
        drawCircle(Color.Red, center = Offset(it.x, it.y), radius = 4f)
  }
}
```

Incidentally, I added the `policy = neverEqualPolicy()` to the `MutableState` because otherwise the `Canvas` only registered the first motion event, and nothing thereafter.

The border is on the `Canvas` so I can see that it is the exact same size and position as the `Box` that is intercepting the motion events above it. (They are indeed in the same position.)

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to draw on a `Canvas`, I think it's cleaner to add pointer detection on itself, to make sure your coordinates are in `Canvas` coordinate spacing.

You had to specify `policy = neverEqualPolicy()` because `MotionEvent` has a single instance with changing values during one touch session, it doesn't meant to be used in Compose in the first place. You can store `Offset` instead like `Offset(motionEffect.x, motionEffect.y)`.

From `pointerInteropFilter` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/pointer/package-summary?hl=pt-br#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).pointerInteropFilter(androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent,kotlin.Function1)):

> Prefer `pointerInput` and use this only for interoperation with existing code that consumes `MotionEvents`.

I'm not sure you actually need `MotionEvents` here. You can use `pointerInput` like this:

```
var touchOffset by remember { mutableStateOf<Offset?>(null) }
Canvas(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(100.dp)
        .fillMaxSize()
        .border(border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Green))
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                touchOffset = change.position
            }
        }
) {
    touchOffset?.let { touchOffset ->
        drawCircle(Color.Red, center = touchOffset, radius = 4f)
    }
}
```

---

If you really need to track touches from top level view for some reason, you can get `Canvas` position in the root view with [`onGloballyPositioned`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/layout/package-summary?hl=PL&skip_cache=true#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).onGloballyPositioned(kotlin.Function1)), and apply it to the touch point:

```
var globalPosition by remember { mutableStateOf<Offset?>(null) }
Canvas(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(100.dp)
        .fillMaxSize()
        .border(border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Green))
        .onGloballyPositioned {
            globalPosition = it.positionInRoot()
        }
) {
    globalPosition?.let { globalPosition ->
        touchOffset?.let { touchOffset ->
            drawCircle(Color.Red, center = touchOffset - globalPosition, radius = 4f)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: THanks Philip. I'm looking into switching to pointerInput, as you suggested. I have found that pointerInteropFilter has a lot of problems, especially inside a LazyItemScope. Can pointerInput capture things like the tool used (eg finger versus stylus), stylus button presses and touch pressure? I need all those things for my app.

Comment: @John I think it should, but I don't have a stylus to check out by myself =)

Comment: I seem to have found everything except pressure. I can't find a single mention of the word pressure anywhere in the docs. It seems like a strange omission...

Comment: @John It looks like the compose API does not currently have this information. I suggest you [create](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128&template=1604926) a feature request. Before that, it looks like you really have to use `pointerInteropFilter`, for that case the second part of my answer should work.